# Automatic timestamp in Slick 3 - null on insert

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I've defined column like this:

```
def lastChecked = column[Timestamp]("LAST_CHECKED", O.Default(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())))
```

And when I insert data in the table I'm omitting this column. But Slick inserts this column as null value. How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need provide default value to field on DB level. For HSQLDB define column in this way:

```
last_checked TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

In slick will be enough to define field with timestamp type:

```
val lastChecked: Rep[java.sql.Timestamp] = column[java.sql.Timestamp]("last_checked")
```

According to slick documantation *O.Default* used only for DDL statements.

Comment: @Xakernfoffe I'm using HSQLDB and it doesn't support function as default value for column. So I want to do this in code

Comment: @user2975535 use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for TIMESTAMP  type. (http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html - create table chapter)